# Functions that sum to zero under cyclic index permutations?

Tags: special-functions

Consider $n$ real vectors of arbitrary dimension $x_i$ with $i\in \{1,2,...,n\}$. Furthermore, consider a function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ where actually the function can only depend on scalars $x_i\cdot x_j$ so that $i,j\in \{1,2,3\}$ count as input variables and other $x_i$ count as parameters. I am interested to find out what kinds of functions $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ sum to zero under cyclic index permutations:

$$0=f(x_1,x_2,x_3)+f(x_2,x_3,x_1)+f(x_3,x_1,x_2)$$

The last two arguments in each case may be permutation invariant:

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(x_1,x_3,x_2)$$

etc. Does anyone know of a class of functions that have this behavior? Or maybe there is a procedure that can be applied to figure this out? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: What should the domain of the function be?

Comment: Start with any function $F(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and define $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = F(x_1,x_2,x_3) + F(x_2,x_3,x_1) + F(x_3,x_1,x_2)$$

Comment: That doesn't work, maybe you were thinking about something like $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=F(x_1,x_2,x_3)+F(x_2,x_3,x_1)-2F(x_3,x_1,x_2)$$

Comment: Ok, I will edit the question to make it more concise.